# How do I install Capistrano?

Tags: 10.10, ruby, gems

I'm struggling here with no success in order to install capistrano on my Ubuntu dev machine.

Here is the list of commands issued:

1) sudo apt-get update

2) sudo apt-get install build-essential git-core curl

3) bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )

4) echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc

5) (close and reopen terminal window)

6) rvm notes

(looked for: "For Ruby (MRI & ree)  you should install the following OS dependencies:"

and did:

7) sudo aptitude install build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev

Now we can install ruby by doing:

8) rvm install 1.9.2

Then we tell rvm to use it:

9) rvm 1.9.2

And to do it always:

10) rvm --default use 1.9.2

With ruby properly instaled we can now:

11) gem install capistrano

And then:

12) gem install railsless-deploy

Despite all those steps being successful steps, when I do:
cap -T

I'm unable to see the deploy tasks listed as expected.

I only getting:
cap invoke
cap shell

listed.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your application have a Capfile? If not, then [read the friendly documentation](https://github.com/leehambley/railsless-deploy/blob/master/README.markdown).

Comment: @Adam: I didn't get your answer. Sorry. If I read the friendly documentation, at some point I get: "Open your application's Capfile and make it begins like this:" but I have no capfile I believe. Please advice... :s I mean, capfile is related to the project that I get, but I don't have the project yet, so I just want to understand what steps should I make, in order to have capistrano with railsless applied... :s

Comment: You should initialize Capistrano for your project by running 'capify .' in the project root. This would create the initial Capfile. If you don't have a project yet, what are you trying to deploy?

Comment: @Adam: I'm trying to deploy nothing at the moment. I thought that, even before I start to use 'capify .' I would need to install capistrano, properly. And in order to use capistrano to deploy other things that are NOT ruby on rails applications, that I needed to have railsless-deploy. Once I got all this, then, by doing cap -T we would get all the tasks available to us. But I only get two instead of the expected 10 or so task availables when I do "cap -T". Only after this I thought, I can actually try the application and do as you say: capify . - or is this wrong? Please have patience. :)

Comment: I don't have experience with railsless, but I'm under impression that you need to have a Capify file containing "require 'railsless-deploy'" (as the documentation suggests) in order to see all the tasks.

Comment: @Adam: Thanks a lot. I think that to. Even if that's true, (and I will test it) that seems to imply that, in order to use cap -T command, I will need to do that command inside my project folder some how, so to use cap deploy, I need first to navigate to my project folder? Is this what you do at the moment? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you might want to post this question in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/